# Displaying certain records from MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, records

I want to display only certain records from my products table

Structure of products table:
[image: products structure]

Structure of suppliers table:
[image: suppliers table]

I want to display all product IDs, product descriptions, product prices, and the supplier company name and contact phone number for all products and list them in descending order of price.  How do I do this using MySQL?

Comment: Not all the columns you want to query seem to be in the structure you've provided

Comment: jmc we are glad to do this. how about text output like 2 or 3 create table statements

Comment: i think i need to    do an  join between products and suppliers to show  all the  colummns i want to right? but i dont think the supp_id(supplier id) on my products table is a forgein key is their anyway i can   make it a forgein key now?

Comment: just show us the supplier suppliers table what ever it is called

Comment: ok ive  edited the question with suppliers  table structure.

Comment: ok all set hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per your edited post] you need to `JOIN` with both table and Add a `ORDER BY Price DESC` in your `SELECT` statement; like

```
select p.`prod_id`, p.`prod_name`, 
p.`price`, s.`company_name`,
s.`phone`
from products p join suppliers s on p.supp_id = s.supp_id
order by p.`price` desc;
```

Comment: sorry i need   to edi the question i didnt provide you with the correct table structures  as drew rightly said...

Comment: k if you say so. look above

Comment: when i   run your  statement it says....

#1146 - Table 'computer_wholesale.supplier' doesn't exist

Comment: sorry? i dont quite get you.

Comment: @jmc1690, I think your actual table name is `suppliers` and I mistyped as `supplier`. Edited the answer. Again those are simple enough for you to correct ... right? I would recommend you start reading through a SQL tutorial (probably `MySQL` tutorial only).

Comment: Rahul didn't ever reference computer_wholesa bla bla